# Javascript:JSllint regular expression literal can be confuse with /=

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have wrote some javascript to split string if "=" sign is there

For example. 
key=value
string="id=abc=xyz"
In the above example I have to split string base on "=" sign, and store them into key and value pair. In this example I am going to store key as "id" and value as a "abc=xyz". to split this I have added following code to store value. It working fine. but my Jslint says "regular expression literal can be confuse with /=".

```
var value=string.split(/=(.+)/)[1];
```

Any pointer for this.

Comment: http://jslinterrors.com/a-regular-expression-literal-can-be-confused-with/

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that's just JSLint being too strict and ignore it. It's extremely clear in your code that you have a RegExp literal and not a `/=` operator.

If you feel the need to fix it you could you the RegExp constructor instead of a literal:

```
var value = string.split(new RegExp('=(.+)'))[1];
```

Or just escape the `=` character:

```
var value = string.split(/\=(.+)/)[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for details. But in IE am getting javascript error.

Comment: @Raje -- IE's strange regexp support isn't really a JSLint issue any more. What version are you using, and what issue?  It looks like [IE8's regexp support is a little wonky](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/cross-browser-split). Even on IE9, I only get one return value with your regexp and `string = "this=little=piggy";`, but, again, that's not really a JSLint issue any more.  This might be a place where, for crossbrowser purposes and expediency, you ditch the regexp.  `value = string.substring(string.indexOf("=")+1);`